# ImageMagick mogrify does not overwrite original files

Tags: format, imagemagick

I would like to convert image formats.

I can use 'convert' command, but it made another image.

So I searched and find 'mogrify' command in ImageMagick official page.

What I did was

```
mogrify -format png a.jpg
```

What I expected was one image that has 'png' extension.

But it did not overwrite original image, but made another png image in my folder.

How Can I get only one image(that means overwite original file) in some format

that I want?

Thanks:-)

Comment: Are you trying to create a .jpg file with PNG data in it?

Comment: @DarthAndroid no. I want to change format bmp to png. upper one is just sample

Comment: regarding the site, they say if i use that -format function, overwrite will not happen. So How Can I make this force overwrite? <-- this is what I actually curios of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ImageMagick's `mogrify` isn't the best tool here, turns out `convert` is much better suited for the job. It can be done by specifying output format with the file name.

```
convert a.jpg png:a.jpg
```

Example:

```
$ file a.jpg 
a.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
$ convert a.jpg png:a.jpg
$ file a.jpg 
a.jpg: PNG image data, 300 x 199, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```